# Error en migraciones tablas relacionadas laravel 8

Tags: laravel

estoy empezando un proyecto en laravel y tengo el primer problema, quiero hacer una tabla tarifas y que la tabla users tenga una clave foranea que apunte a su id, lo intento (despues de muchas pruebas) así:

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tarifas', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine=("InnoDB");
        $table->bigIncrements('id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Y la de users así:

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('tarifa_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->foreign('tarifa_id')->references('id')->on('tarifas');
    });
}
```

pero me lanza este error:

```
1   C:\xampp\htdocs\****\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:495
  PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' engine = InnoDB' at line 1")
2 C:\xampp\htdocs****\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:495 PDO::prepare("create table users () default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' engine = InnoDB")
```

¿Alguien me puede ayudar? Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Recuerda que los errores deben ir _como texto, con formato_, ya que no todos pueden visualizar las imágenes (es más, la imagen actual tiene letras muy pequeñas). Aún así: se ve que no se toman las columnas en el `CREATE TABLE`, entonces, desde mi desconocimiento te pregunto: ¿es correcto que tengas dos veces la misma definición para `Schema::create('users'`(...)?

Comment: Ya lo he editado, gracias.
En cuanto a lo del doble Create, lo lei en algún foro y fue la ultima prueba que hice de muchas. Al quitarlo, me funciona perfecto, gracias.

Comment: En ese caso, si ya lograste resolver tu problema, ponlo como respuesta (en base a [answer]), y [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.

Comment: También, siempre es buena idea leer la [documentación oficial](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints). Leer esa página te puede llevar entre 15 y 30 minutos, y tendrás una visión general de cómo maneja laravel las migraciones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues al final el problema lo causé probando, lo resolví gracias al comentario de @paladeiana, eliminando el doble create, quedó tal que así:

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tarifas', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine=("InnoDB");
        $table->bigIncrements('id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Y los users:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('tarifa_id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('tarifa_id')->references('id')->on('tarifas');
    });
}
```

Tal y como dice la documentación oficial que me aconsejo @porloscerros Ψ.
Espero que a alguien le sirva.